# Hypergeometric differential equation with integer parameters?

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

Naively, the hypergeometric differential equation has two independent solutions as follows:

```
fun=y[x]/.DSolve[(x (1 - x) y''[x] + (c - (a + b + 1) x) y'[x] - a b y[x]) == 0, y[x], x][[1]]
```

> [image]

Let's say we are interested in obtaining the solution for `a,b,c` integer, e.g.

```
subabc={a->5,b->4,c->3};
```

Substituting this in just gives infinity:

```
fun/.subabc
```

> `ComplexInfinity`

While substituting the parameters into the differential equation before solving it, gives a perfectly finite result:

```
y[x]/.DSolve[((x (1 - x) y''[x] + (c - (a + b + 1) x) y'[x] - a b y[x])/.subabc) == 0, y[x], x][[1]]
```

> [image]

Is there a way to make Mathematica return a valid analytic result that would reduce to the explicit example upon inserting integer parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are assuming positive integer parameters, use [a linear transformation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E7) on the second independent solution:

```
expr = DSolveValue[(x (1 - x) y''[x] + (c - (a + b + 1) x) y'[x] - a b y[x]) == 0,
                   y[x], x] // MapAt[# /. Hypergeometric2F1[a_, b_, c_, z_] :> 
                                     Pochhammer[c - b, -a]/Pochhammer[c, -a]
                                     Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, b - c + a + 1, 1 - z] &, 2]
```

which yields

```
C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x] + ((-1)^(1 - c) x^(1 - c) Pochhammer[1 - b, -1 - a + c]
C[2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a - c, 1 + b - c, 1 + a + b - c, 1 - x])/
Pochhammer[2 - c, -1 - a + c]
```

This behaves fine for positive integer parameters:

```
expr /. Thread[{a, b, c} -> {5, 4, 3}]
   ((3 + 2 x) C[1])/(3 (1 - x)^6) +
   (C[2] (1 - 12 x - 36 x^2 + 44 x^3 + 3 x^4 - 36 x^2 Log[x] - 24 x^3 Log[x]))/
   ((-1 + x)^6 x^2)
```

Comment: This is curious! I thought the linear transformations were only valid when one of the upper parameters is a negative integer, making the whole thing a polynomial. How come it is valid here too, did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, I've found they produce solutions that still satisfy the hypergeometric DE if the denominator parameter would otherwise degenerate to a negative integer. I haven't fully investigated why yet.

Comment: Very interesting! Perhaps it just shifts to a different independent pair from the 24 Kummer solutions...